# MIGRATING ORACLE FORMS 6I TO 12C

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, oracleforms

The data_parameter constant will not work when used in conjunction with run_report_object() . I am getting this message while migrating oracle forms 6I to oracle forms 12C. Please give me solution for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, `DATA_PARAMETER` can't be used in `RUN_REPORT_OBJECT` Forms versions newer than 10g (though, it can be used in `RUN_PRODUCT`).

See if you can use `TEXT_PARAMETER` instead.

See if [Integrating Oracle Reports with Oracle Forms](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/forms/documentation/formsreportsintegration-12c-3014203.pdf) (for Oracle Fusion Middleware 12c) helps.

Furthermore, there's another document within the *Fusion Middleware documentation library* you could/should read (if you didn't do it yet): “Oracle Forms: Upgrading Oracle Forms 6i to Oracle Forms 12c".